# Get POIs in a given city and category from Foursquare API

Tags: php, foursquare

I want to use the Foursquare-API to get venues in a given city. The API has two endpoints that could help me with my problem:
`venue/explore` and `venue/search`

Now the problem is, that both of them are missing features I would need that the other endpoint has. For example, I cannot use the explore endpoint, because I'm not able to pass category ids to the foursquare api to search only in given categories.

So now I already **have** to use the search endpoint, but the search endpoint has another problem. The intent parameter. The intent parameter accepts `checkin, browse, global, match`

`checkin` finds pois that the user would check in at the current moment in time. Problem: I want to run a cronjob at night, so it would never find a museum, 'cause it's probably closed at night.

`browse` has the problem, that I have to pass a radius parameter. But since not every city has the same radius I would also find results of other cities in my search request. As example, if I search for pois in Cologne, and have a radius of 30km, I would also find POIs in Duesseldorf. But in some other cities the radius of 30km is a good one and I would only find POIs in the given city. I can't tell for sure that I have the correct radius.

`global` searches independent of the location so it's also useless

`match` doesn't include categories so it's also useless

Ok, let's sum it up together, what I need to do

I need to find Locations that are in a certain city, and have specific categories only!
I built myself this url here to query data from foursquare

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20141124&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,503288ae91d4c4b30a586d67,4bf58dd8d48988d1c8941735,4bf58dd8d48988d14e941735,4bf58dd8d48988d152941735,4bf58dd8d48988d107941735,4bf58dd8d48988d142941735,4bf58dd8d48988d169941735&intent=browse&radius=5000&limit=50&near=35.6894875,139.69170639999993

This now returns venues from Tokyo: (I limited it to 3, so we don't have too much data displayed here)

```
{
   "meta":{
      "code":200
   },
   "response":{
      "venues":[
         {
            "id":"4b7af3d1f964a520e3472fe3",
            "name":"伊勢丹 新宿店 (Isetan Shinjuku)",
            "contact":{
               "phone":"+81333521111",
               "formattedPhone":"+81 3-3352-1111"
            },
            "location":{
               "address":"新宿3-14-1",
               "lat":35.69167888630371,
               "lng":139.70466434955597,
               "postalCode":"160-0022",
               "cc":"JP",
               "city":"新宿区",
               "state":"東京都",
               "country":"Japan",
               "formattedAddress":[
                  "新宿3-14-1",
                  "新宿区, Tōkyō",
                  "160-0022",
                  "Japan"
               ]
            },
            "categories":[
               {
                  "id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1f6941735",
                  "name":"Kaufhaus",
                  "pluralName":"Kaufhäuser",
                  "shortName":"Kaufhaus",
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/departmentstore_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  },
                  "primary":true
               }
            ],
            "verified":false,
            "stats":{
               "checkinsCount":38525,
               "usersCount":14542,
               "tipCount":104
            },
            "url":"http:\/\/www.isetan.co.jp\/icm2\/jsp\/store\/shinjuku\/",
            "specials":{
               "count":0,
               "items":[

               ]
            },
            "hereNow":{
               "count":0,
               "summary":"Keiner hier",
               "groups":[

               ]
            },
            "referralId":"v-1416841962"
         },
         {
            "id":"4b6a8c00f964a5204fd82be3",
            "name":"東急 田園都市線 渋谷駅",
            "contact":{
               "phone":"+81354585143",
               "formattedPhone":"+81 3-5458-5143"
            },
            "location":{
               "address":"道玄坂2-1-1",
               "lat":35.65325468817092,
               "lng":139.69734217064342,
               "cc":"JP",
               "city":"渋谷区",
               "state":"東京都",
               "country":"Japan",
               "formattedAddress":[
                  "道玄坂2-1-1",
                  "渋谷区, Tōkyō",
                  "Japan"
               ]
            },
            "categories":[
               {
                  "id":"4bf58dd8d48988d129951735",
                  "name":"Bahnhof",
                  "pluralName":"Bahnhöfe",
                  "shortName":"Bahnhof",
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/travel\/trainstation_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  },
                  "primary":true
               }
            ],
            "verified":false,
            "stats":{
               "checkinsCount":51145,
               "usersCount":6686,
               "tipCount":21
            },
            "specials":{
               "count":0,
               "items":[

               ]
            },
            "hereNow":{
               "count":0,
               "summary":"Keiner hier",
               "groups":[

               ]
            },
            "referralId":"v-1416841962"
         },
         {
            "id":"543365cd498e6a226ce59c11",
            "name":"la kagu ラカグ",
            "contact":{
               "phone":"+81352276977",
               "formattedPhone":"+81 3-5227-6977",
               "twitter":"la_kagu",
               "facebook":"470802349690219",
               "facebookUsername":"lakagu.kagurazaka",
               "facebookName":"ラカグ　la kagu"
            },
            "location":{
               "address":"矢来町67",
               "lat":35.70377775661292,
               "lng":139.73318235755823,
               "postalCode":"162-0805",
               "cc":"JP",
               "city":"Tokyo",
               "state":"東京都",
               "country":"Japan",
               "formattedAddress":[
                  "矢来町67",
                  "新宿区, Tōkyō",
                  "162-0805",
                  "Japan"
               ]
            },
            "categories":[
               {
                  "id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1f8941735",
                  "name":"Möbel- \/ Einrichtungsgeschäft",
                  "pluralName":"Möbel- \/ Einrichtungsgeschäfte",
                  "shortName":"Möbel \/ Einrichtung",
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/furniture_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  },
                  "primary":true
               }
            ],
            "verified":false,
            "stats":{
               "checkinsCount":468,
               "usersCount":429,
               "tipCount":5
            },
            "url":"http:\/\/www.lakagu.com",
            "specials":{
               "count":0,
               "items":[

               ]
            },
            "hereNow":{
               "count":0,
               "summary":"Keiner hier",
               "groups":[

               ]
            },
            "referralId":"v-1416841962"
         }
      ],
      "geocode":{
         "what":"",
         "where":"35.6894875,139.69170639999993",
         "feature":{
            "cc":"JP"
         },
         "parents":[

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This now has multiple problems:

1. The city names are in the country language (not in English)
2. The foursquare API for this search returns Shibuya for a city (as an example) which is a special ward, and not a city and Tokyo for the state. However, in Germany the city is the city, like Cologne and state is the state, like Northrhine-Westphalia

This leads to the problem, that I can't easily compare the cities to see if the POI is in the requested City. I could however check if the city or the state matches, but this could be different in every country, so I see that as a problem.

So, what is the best way to get only cities in a given city for specific categories independent of time, location etc. and filter out pois from cities that are not the requested city?